# Autoplay in NextJs slick slider not working when number of slides is eqaul to slidesToShow

Tags: reactjs, next.js, carousel, react-slick

I am using Slick slider in NextJs. Everything is working fine except that when the number of slide items is equal the value of slidesToShow, the infinite autoplay ceases to work. Is there a way to go around this.

Comment: you kind of answered your own question

Comment: @jsotola, yes I know its the default behaviour but will still need them for a continuous scroll kind-of feature. Do you know an other NextJs component that can help me achieve this? Thank you in advance

Comment: no, I do not ... I would simply have more slide items than slidesToShow